# How to animate stroke to draw in JQuery from 0 to 100% when I hover over canvas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to animate the strokes that link my div's together but I would like to animate them from 0 to 100% when element is hovered over, would anyone have a solution?

So I am trying to animate the line so they draw from a point A to completion in point Z. I hope you can understand better with the code.
here is the website : https://willowy-rolypoly-66ca67.netlify.app/

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
 <div>
                <div id="content">
                  <div id="div1" class="mydiv">
                    <a class="indeximg" data-img="img/pbb-articles_Page_08.png" data-imgid="article08"
                      data-line="lineArticle08" data-scrollable="true" data-border="true">
                      <img class="intro" src="./img/machineLearning.png" alt="">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id="div2" class="mydiv">
                    <a class="indeximg" data-img="img/pbb-articles_Page_02.png" data-imgid="article02"
                      data-line="lineArticle02" data-scrollable="true" data-border="true">

                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id="div3" class="mydiv">
                    <a class="indeximg" data-img="img/pbb-articles_Page_03.png" data-imgid="article03"
                      data-line="lineArticle03" data-scrollable="true" data-border="true">
                      <img src="./img/lotus.png" alt="">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id="div4" class="mydiv">
                    <a class="indeximg" data-img="img/pbb-articles_Page_09.png" data-imgid="article09"
                      data-line="lineArticle09" data-scrollable="true" data-imganimation="zoom" data-border="true">
                      <img class="intro" src="./img/machineLearning.png" alt="">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id="div5" class="mydiv">
                    <a class="indeximg" data-img="img/pbb-articles_Page_10.png" data-imgid="article10"
                      data-line="lineArticle10" data-scrollable="true" data-imganimation="zoom" data-border="true">
                      <img src="./img/machineLearning.png" alt="">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id="div6" class="mydiv">
                    <a class="indeximg" data-img="img/pbb-articles_Page_01.png" data-imgid="article01"
                      data-line="lineArticle01" data-scrollable="true" data-imganimation="zoom" data-border="true">
                      <img class="intro" src="./img/machineLearning.png" alt="">
                          </a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class=" line" id="line1"></div>
                  <div class="line" id="line2"></div>
                  <div class="line" id="line3"></div>
                  <div class="line" id="line4"></div>
                  <div class="line" id="line5"></div>
                  <div class="line" id="line6"></div>
                  <div class="line" id="line7"></div>
                </div>
```

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    function loop() {
      adjustLine($('#div1'), $('.canvas-box'), $('#line1'));
      adjustLine($('#div2'), $('.canvas-box'), $('#line2'));
      adjustLine($('#div3'), $('.canvas-box'), $('#line3'));
      adjustLine($('#div4'), $('.canvas-box'), $('#line4'));
      adjustLine($('#div5'), $('.canvas-box'), $('#line5'));
      adjustLine($('#div6'), $('.canvas-box'), $('#line6'));

    function adjustLine(from, to, line) {
      if (from.length === 0 || to.length === 0 || line.length === 0) {
        return;
      }
```

Comment: Where's the part of the code that actually does something? Please see [ask] about creating a [mre].

Comment: Your code is missing the `}` to close both functions - this is obvious to see when you format your code correctly, as I've done in the edit. Can you please update the question to include all relevant HTML and CSS

Comment: Thanks for the help and feedback, I corrected and added some more code to make it more understandable.